# AWS RDS seems to only process 3 requests at a time

Tags: amazon-rds

I've got a laravel service that loads a reactjs page that fires off around 30+ axios calls after loading. When I look at the source tab, it looks like only 3 of the calls are being processed at a time.

I'm testing this by connecting to the AWS RDS instance from my local environment. I tried using a db.t3.medium and a db.t3.large with no noticeable change.

The applicate has multiple database connections. Each requests uses all three connection to gather the required data. All of the requests execute the exact same query from one database and then each of the requests executes a query on a different table in the second database.

Is there a reason why AWS isn't processing all of my requests simultaneously?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Load Balancer? Did you try to monitoring with CloudWatch logs of Database ?

Comment: I see a reference to cloudwatch but I don't know how to use it. I'll look into that more. I don't know if I'm using a load balancer.

Comment: @IsmoilShifoev Is "CloudWatch logs of Database"  referring to all of the graphs on the RDS dashboard, like "CPU Utilization" and "DB Connections" etc?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html

Comment: @IsmoilShifoev The bottom of that page mentions "Viewing Metrics by Using the Console" and shows a picture of the graphs on the RDS console. This is what I've been watching and non of the data looks concerning. What metric should I look at/for?

Comment: You can just set RDS metric by database class name and here you can choose on which type of machine you set up. There are some type log audit, general and other log that show you the logs. But you can see CPU utilization too you just need to reed doc properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188977/discussion-between-ismoil-shifoev-and-ethan22).

Answer (score 0):

You aren’t looking at the good performance indicator. You are looking at your browser network console. Your browser limits the number of request it can do on the same host simultaneously.

You can find more information here: [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)